# vimgrep search for known char string yields E480 error message

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I'm attempting to use vimgrep to run a very simple search for all occurences of the character string "proj" in all text files in the current folder. The directory is called "logs" and all the files have the same naming scheme: "log_yyyymmdd.txt".

I'm running the command `:vimgrep /proj/g *.txt` with "logs" as the current directory

I know that the character string occurs across multiple files in that folder, but the error message `E480: No match: proj` continues to appear.

Help appreciated.

GilF

Answer (score 1):

Your command seems to be perfect. You can give a try with the following

```
:vim /proj/g `find . -name "*.txt" -type f`
```

OR

```
:grep proj *.txt
```

Comment: Hi Amit. Thanks for speedy reply! I entered the first of your suggested commands verbatim and got this message:                                                       `"Access denied -."[New File]
"File not found - -NAME" [New File]
"File not found - -TYPE" [New File]
"File not found - -F" [New File]
Cannot open file "File not found - - F"
E480: No match: proj`

Comment: @user2962912 What platform are you on? I tested these commands and they work fine for me.

Comment: I tried the second and got this message:                                                            `:!findstr /n proj *.txt>C:Users\Name\AppData\Local\Tep\VIeB0F4.tmp 2>&1 [No write since last change]
shell returned 1

Comment: I am using gvim on Windows 7, sorry should have made that clear at start.

Comment: Sorry, then these won't work there. Please try with `:g/proj/p *txt`

Comment: `E486: Pattern not found: proj`

Answer (score 0):

The `E480` is about matching *files*, not pattern matches. Therefore, Vim does not find any of your log files, despite the pattern `*.txt` (which should match).

As `:vimgrep` obeys the `'wildignore'` option, I think this prevents it from searching those files. Check with `:set wildignore?` and try removing the pattern / all via `:set wildignore=`.

Comment: Hello Ingo, Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. GilF